# The sentence that starts as imperative one and ends in passive voice

Tags: sentence-choice, syntax

There is a following passage in the technical manual I'm working on:

> To replace invalid characters, complete the following steps:
>
> 1. ...
> 2. ...
> 3. ...

The problem is that writing the steps themselves in the 2nd person would be very awkward. Compare the following versions of the first step:

> - Colons, dashes, commas that can be replaced by dashes, periods that separate sentences, semicolons that can be replaced by periods, ellipses, question marks, exclamation marks, and parentheses are replaced by hyphens. (3rd person, passive voice)
> - Replace colons, dashes, commas that can be replaced by dashes, periods that separate sentences, semicolons that can be replaced by periods, ellipses, question marks, exclamation marks, and parentheses with hyphens. (2nd person, active voice)

For the reason that steps will be written in the 3rd person, the sentence that introducing the list need to be changed.

- To replace invalid characters, the following steps should be completed:
- For invalid characters to be replaced, the following steps should be completed:

The second version seems to be grammatically safe, but -- from my own perspective, and since I'm not a native speaker of English, this perspective might be wrong -- is awkward.

The first sentence is shorter and probably better, but I'm not sure it is correct. Is it?

Comment: You're making the transfer of information unnecessarily difficult because you're effectively trying to convert a ***tabular*** specification (that enormous list) into a "natural language" format. Any style guide will tell you that "3rd person, passive voice" doesn't convey information efficiently because it doesn't ***engage*** the reader the way "2nd person, active voice" does. In version #'2 it's poor style to make the reader remember ***replace*** for so long before reaching the matching word ***with***. I suggest you rephrase to ***Replace the following with hyphens: [long list].***

Comment: (That's to say, your context isn't really suitable for a "natural language" utterance. We're just trying to make the best of a bad job.)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thanks, excellent suggestion. Such an approach will also help me to change a few other 3rd person passages.

Comment: In general, your command of English is pretty impressive for a non-native Anglophone. But just because you *know* how to use more complex constructions (not just as regards *verbs*) doesn't mean you *should* often use them. Also, sometimes you just gotta trust your reader to "infer" a certain amount of information without it being explicitly stated (just because the simplest way of saying something is potentially "ambiguous" isn't a problem if the context makes it reasonably obvious which meaning is intended). So I hope your upcoming "simplification review" bears fruit on that front! :)